# How to obtain POJO out of a URL

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, pojo, okhttp

I am trying to convert the following link
[this](https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=:query)

into POJO, so I tried [this website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

but it tells me the following:

```
 Your input was larger than 51200 characters, try making this a bit  
 smaller
```

is there any way to obtain the POJO out of the aforementioned link?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the CLI and using that instead of the webservice?

https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started#the-command-line-interface